# asp.net cookies are getting overwritten

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have an asp.net web application with one drop down box containing language preferences (English, French). When I select French I write cookie as following -

```
protected void ddChoice_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("pref");
        cookie.Value = ddChoice.SelectedValue;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ddChoice.SelectedValue);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddChoice.SelectedValue);           
        Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
    }
```

and read this cookie in begin request as follows  -

```
      protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

            string lang = string.Empty;//default to the invariant culture
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["pref"];

           if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value.Trim()))
            lang = cookie.Value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang))
            lang = "en-US"; 

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
      }
```

This time if I check the browser cookie it is rightly set to "fr-FR". But after this, when I go to home page and refresh this page cookie gets set to blank.

I'm not sure where it is getting overwritten. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `ddChoice_SelectedIndexChanged` event is generated with empty `SelectedValue` and therefore your cookie is empty. Try to put breakpoint in the mehod or comment it out.

Comment: Nope. Test case is - 1. Go to home page - default language (English), 2. Change language - it gets changed, 3. Go to home page - rightly with selected language (French), 4. Hit F5 - language should remain french, but gets reset to English.

Comment: Why is there `Server.Transfer(Request.Path)`?

Comment: "The Transfer method sends all of the information that has been assembled for processing by one .asp file to a second .asp file." So it causes page reload. Isn't it the problem? Can you try to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

As your test case in the step 4 when you hit F5 page getting postback and language dropdown of language gets set with the default top language.

For that you need to write a function in control or page where your language dropdown is placed which set the selected lanaguage.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
        setLangDropdown();
      }
}
private void setLangDropdown()
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["pref"];
    string lang = string.Empty;

    if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value.Trim()))
        lang = cookie.Value;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang))
        ddChoice.SelectedValue = lang;  
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("pref");
    cookie.Value = ddChoice.SelectedValue;
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    Response.SetCookie(cookie);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(ddChoice.SelectedValue);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(ddChoice.SelectedValue);



    }
```